# Popping when I do the bicycle crunches

Tags: crunches

I am having a popping in the backside of my hip when I do the bicycle crunches and similar exercises. Is it normal or bad? What should I do about this?

Comment: "Popping" is too broad of a term for us to diagnose. Best to see a doctor about this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that popping sound is nothing more than [air pockets](https://orthopedicassociates.org/when-is-joint-popping-a-problem/) in your joint (which is normal and won't actually hurt you).
However, if you are experiencing pain when you hear the popping sound, it could be something else, in which case you should see a physician.
I would still go see a doctor to make sure that everything is okay, even if there is no pain.